# Get last working directory of completed process

Tags: unix, ocaml

Is it possible to get the last working directory of a completed process? For example: we've forked a process, waited for it to complete, obtained an exit code and some output, and now we want to examine the last working directory the process was in.

Our application is written in OCaml, so here's the roughly equivalent code:

```
open Core.Std

let pinfo = Unix.create_process ~prog:"/bin/sh" ~args:["-c"; "cd ~/foo/bar"] in
let open Unix.Process_info in
let _ = Unix.waitpid pinfo.pid in
(* what was the last working directory of pinfo.pid? *)
```

Any suggestions, whether OCaml specific or not, would be greatly appreciated! Also, a solution that works on both MacOSX and Linux would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Linux kernel provides that information. If the application is a black box, you could potentially use an `LD_PRELOAD` or `strace` to track `chdir()` calls.